# Error in vba code to save to master worksheet

Tags: vba, excel

I've currently set up an macro which is temperamental at the best of times. The spreadsheet is used to report daily trading data which is uploaded onto separate worksheets. Once the vba is run, the selected worksheet is embedded into the body of an email and the workbook is also attached before being sent out to the relevant groups. The second part of the VBA is designed to save each individual worksheet on to one master worksheet once the vba script is running.

However, this element of it throws up various issues, with everything not always saving to the master worksheet as intended. [image: here is a screenshot of a day's trading data before the vba is run]

After it has been run, the data does not always transfer onto a master worksheet which is the primary concern, sometimes it remains blank and other times it does not copy data to the master worksheet correctly.

I've attached the part of the vba which is most relevant to this question. Any general advice on where I might be going wrong in the code would be greatly appreciated.

```
    Sub AppendDataAfterLastColumn()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Dim DestSh As Worksheet
    Dim Last As Long
    Dim CopyRng As Range

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = False
        .EnableEvents = False
    End With

    'Delete the sheet "RDBMergeSheet" if it exist
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    'Add a worksheet with the name "RDBMergeSheet"
    Set DestSh = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    DestSh.Name = "RDBMergeSheet"
   Last = Cells(1, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column


    'loop through all worksheets and copy the data to the DestSh
    For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
        If sh.Name <> DestSh.Name Then

            'Fill in the column(s) that you want to copy
            Set CopyRng = sh.Range("A:G")

            'Test if there enough rows in the DestSh to copy all the data
            If Last + CopyRng.Columns.Count > DestSh.Columns.Count Then
                MsgBox "There are not enough columns in the Destsh"
                GoTo ExitTheSub
            End If

            'This example copies values/formats and Column width
            CopyRng.Copy
            With DestSh.Cells(1, Last + 1)
                .PasteSpecial 8    ' Column width
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats
                Application.CutCopyMode = False
            End With

        End If
    Next

ExitTheSub:

    Application.Goto DestSh.Cells(1)

    With Application
        .ScreenUpdating = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With
End Sub
```

[image: this is the point where it fails to move on to the master worksheet sub]

```
    Function RangetoHTML(rng As Range)
' Changed by Ron de Bruin 28-Oct-2006
' Working in Office 2000-2016
    Dim fso As Object
    Dim ts As Object
    Dim TempFile As String
    Dim TempWB As Workbook

    TempFile = Environ$("temp") & "\" & Format(Now, "dd-mm-yy h-mm-ss") & ".htm"

    'Copy the range and create a new workbook to past the data in
    rng.Copy
    Set TempWB = Workbooks.Add(1)
    With TempWB.Sheets(1)
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=8
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, , False, False
        .Cells(1).PasteSpecial xlPasteFormats, , False, False
        .Cells(1).Select
        Application.CutCopyMode = False
        On Error Resume Next
        .DrawingObjects.Visible = True
        .DrawingObjects.Delete
        On Error GoTo 0
    End With

    'Publish the sheet to a htm file
    With TempWB.PublishObjects.Add( _
         SourceType:=xlSourceRange, _
         Filename:=TempFile, _
         Sheet:=TempWB.Sheets(1).Name, _
         Source:=TempWB.Sheets(1).UsedRange.Address, _
         HtmlType:=xlHtmlStatic)
        .Publish (True)
    End With

    'Read all data from the htm file into RangetoHTML
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set ts = fso.GetFile(TempFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
    RangetoHTML = ts.readall
    ts.Close
    RangetoHTML = Replace(RangetoHTML, "align=center x:publishsource=", _
                          "align=left x:publishsource=")

    'Close TempWB
    TempWB.Close savechanges:=False

    'Delete the htm file we used in this function
    Kill TempFile

    Set ts = Nothing
    Set fso = Nothing
    Set TempWB = Nothing
End Function
```

Comment: I suggest you to debug your code. Execute it Step by Step using F8. Then, that way, you can discover at what exact moment the code does something unexpected. Check it out

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I've attempted to debug it and it stops prior to beginning  the master workbook section of the code highlighted in my question. I will attach a screen grab for greater clarity/context, essentially the yellow highlighted section titled end function is the point it reaches, before doing a loop and running that sub again, rather than running the master worksheet function below it. Is this a syntax error or am I missing something? I apologise for the very general questions, I have tried to troubleshoot it myself but no luck so far.

Comment: In VBA, when you call a Function, it executes the code of the Function, but after it's done, it should return to the line of code where you call the Function. Where does it go after it ends Function?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns It returns to the start of the function again. Does this mean I need to restructure where I place the function phrase? And do you potentially have any suggestions for where I should place it>

Comment: It starts the function again? It should not. How do you call that function?

Comment: @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns I've attached the section of the function I am referencing at the bottom of my question. Any general advice on this would be awesome.

Comment: Your sub `AppendDataAfterLastColumn()` does not call in any moment your function `RangetoHTML`. They are 2 different procedures. Debug only the code of  `Sub AppendDataAfterLastColumn()` with F8. Rest of code is not necesary. Click in any line of code of only your sub and then press F8 to debug only that sub.

Answer (score 0):

You have On Error GoTo 0 which essentially ignores errors.
That is not what you want.  You'll never find them if you're ignoring them.

Take that code that you are intending to ignore errors for and move it to its own procedure.  This way the skip of error handling is only for that procedure and not the one calling it.  Instead of:

```
 On Error Resume Next
    ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
```

Use this:

```
Private Sub RemoveMergeSheet()

   On Error Resume Next
   ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("RDBMergeSheet").Delete

End Sub
```